# Show true or false (0/1) from a mySQL in checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

```
<input type="text" id="A1" name="A1">
```

In the box above, 0 or 1 is placed from mysql (fetch in box). Now I want that:

value box = 0 >> checkbox is unchecked

value box = 1 >> checkbox is checked

How to use a checkbox (type="checkbox") instead of text (type="text")?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="A1" name="A1">
```

Comment: How is the data being inserted from MySQL? With a plain echo or what ?

Comment: can you explain little bit more on your question @Reza Hatami

Comment: you want fetch the value from data base (true/false) and show in the your html checkbox right?

Comment: @adeneo with a trigger mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check do it like this:

```
<?php
$box_val = 1; // rertive this value from database
?>
<input type="checkbox" id="A1" name="A1" <?=($box_val == 1) ? "checked" : "" ?>>
```

Comment: How after submit form, according to the checkbox status, send 0 or 1 to the database?

Comment: Set value of check box. You will get checkbox value only if check box  is checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
<input id="A1" name="A1" checked="0" type="checkbox">
<script>
    $('#A1').prop("checked",$mySqlValue);
</script>
```

If `$mySqlValue==1` the box will be checked and if `$mySqlValue==0` it will not be checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use js

```
document.getElementById("A1").checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Reza Hatami,**

Try this below code,
`$my_checkbox` variable inside store data retrive from mysql data base.

```
<?php
    $my_checkbox = 1;
?>
<input type="checkbox" id="Notification" name="Notification" <?php echo if($mycheckbox == 1) ? 'checked=""': ""; ?> />
```

also using, But in this some problem is some browser or php version not support so my advise use above code.

```
<?php
   $my_checkbox = 1;
?>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Notification" name="Notification" <?=($my_checkbox == 1) ? "checked" : "" ?> />
```

I hope my answer is helpfull. If any query so comment please.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="A1" name="A1"   <?php if($value==1) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> >
```

`$value` is from database